# Paypal express checkout not working when deployed to heroku.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal checkout into my Rails application and i have ran into a problem making it work when i deploy it to Heroku. It works completely fine in my development environment, but when i try to use it on my production level, the application crashes. I have been following this tutorial: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails

In my rails application I have a registration model and once an registration object is created, it sends the user to the Paypal URL. Once the user finishes his/her payment it sends the user back to my website. 
This is the relevant code used in my controller for the payment:

```
def create
respond_to do |format| 
      if @registration.save
        format.html { redirect_to @registration.paypal_url(yea_school_registration_path(@yea_school, @registration), @amount), notice: "You should recieve an email soon." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @registration }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end
end


   def hook

    params.permit!
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @registration = Registration.find(params[:id]) 
      @registration.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
    end
      render nothings: true
  end
```

This is the code that is needed for the payment process in my controller file. A quick walk down, once the object is created it redirects it to the paypal url, generated through a method in my model. The instance variable @amount isn't actually apart of the registration model. It is apart of a different model used to determine if a user will have any money taken off of their order. Again this worked completely fine in my development environment, so I don't believe this is the issue.

This is the code used to make the url in my model:

```
serialize :notification_params, Hash
  def paypal_url(return_path, amount)
    @amount = amount 
    values = {
    business: "fake@email.com",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{ENV["app_host"]}#{return_path}",
    invoice: id,
    amount: 20 - @amount,
    item_name: "Item",
    item_number: id,
    quantity: '1',
    notify_url: "#{ENV["app_host"]}/hook"
    }
    "#{ENV["paypal_host"]}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

In this, a hash of values is sent to Paypal and the Paypal URL is generated along with the return URL is generated. The app_host is the url of my website and the paypal_url is the url of Paypal. These are kept as environment variables. And I have declared these variables in Heroku. My other environment variables work, so i don't know if that is the issue.

The registration object is being created, but it is not going to Paypal for the payments. Again, this works well in my development environment but when i try to test on my production level, in Heroku, it crashes. I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and very new to Paypal. If you have an answer that wold be awesome and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the heroku logs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Yes, and it shows "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 971ms (ActiveRecord: 18.6ms)" and then "heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/yea_schools/2/registrations" host=desolate-river-8499.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxx fwd="xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=xxxms status=500 bytes=1669" as the last request.

Comment: run `heroku config`. see if your paypal keys are there.

Comment: @ZacharyWalters Nothing obvious to me in the log, however it hight help you to get an answer if you format and paste it into the question for anyone else who shows up.  Unfortunately I don't know much about PayPal's API so other than that suggestion I can't be much help.

Comment: @miler350, i have checked my heroku variables and they are entered correctly, my `app_host` is set to the url generated by heroku for my application and my `paypal_host` is set to "https://www.paypal.com".

Comment: @neanderslob, i want to apologize for not formatting my text correctly. I'm kinda new to stack overflow as well. So here are the last to messages in my logs in heroku: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 971ms (ActiveRecord: 18.6ms)` and the last one is: `heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/yea_schools/2/registrations" host=desolate-river-8499.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxx fwd="xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=xxxms status=500 bytes=1669`.

Comment: @ZacharyWalters, what can you tell me about this url path: `/yea_schools/2/registrations`. Does it look familiar? In other words, its in your `create` method and Heroku is saying, "yeah, that's not going to work". Do you mind posting your `routes.rb` file?